# Nested pie chart from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
product   count  Class
stuff       3      A
thing       7      A
another     1      B
```

I can do 2 different pie charts with my code:

```
my_data = df['count']
my_labels = df['Product']
plt.pie(my_data,labels=my_labels,autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Distribution 1')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()

my_data = df['count']
my_labels = df['Class']
plt.pie(my_data,labels=my_labels,autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Distribution 2')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

but I want to do a nested pie that could combine both:

When I checked https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html
I did not understand how to do it not with static values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write your code more closely according to the link you shared. Just replace the array in the example with your columns. You'll probably have to do some additional formatting with the labels, but perhaps it turns out okay with your actual data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = d1.copy()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.3
vals = np.array([[60., 32.], [37., 40.], [29., 10.]])

cmap = plt.get_cmap("tab20c")
outer_colors = cmap(np.arange(3)*4)
inner_colors = cmap(np.array([1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]))

ax.pie(df.groupby('Class', sort=False)['count'].sum(), radius=1, colors=outer_colors, labels=df['Class'].drop_duplicates(), autopct='%1.1f%%',
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.pie(df['count'], radius=1-size, colors=inner_colors, labels=df['product'], autopct='%1.1f%%',
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.set(aspect="equal", title='Distribution 1 and 2')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe one additional question, is there a way to merge the 2 'A' parts on the outer side? It's the main purpose of my figure.

Comment: @marou95thebest I am not exactly sure what you mean by that.

Comment: in the outer ring there is an red class A and a blue class A. Is there a way to merge them since they are the same?

Comment: the length of the labels need to match the length of the column, which is why I used `unique()` for the first plot to match length of groupby output. I.E. both have to have two values.

Comment: In the new version (without `unique()`), the outside ring is not corresponding with the inside one. By that I mean, that elements from class A are under class B for instance.

Comment: @marou95thebest good spot, I know why that has happened, Ill update my answer. To ensure sorting doesn't mess anything up, I have used: `df.groupby('Class', sort=False)`. Also, I have done `df['Class'].drop_duplicates()` for labels so there should be no issues with resorting and stuff not lining up.

Comment: Thanks, your code works perfectly. It was just the labels that are totally misplaced.

Comment: hmmm... I'm not sure what the issue is. Is it possible to post a new question with some sample data that shows how it goes wrong? The current sample data doesn't show any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the tutorial, you might want to modify it a bit:

size = 0.3

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pie(df.groupby('Class')['count'].sum(), radius=1, 
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.pie(df['count'], radius=1-size, 
       wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'))

ax.set(aspect="equal", title='Pie plot with `ax.pie`')
```

Output:

[image]